# How do I set the html label for autocomplete_light

Tags: django, django-forms, django-autocomplete-light

Looking for a way to indicate the string label for Django's autocomplete_light form fields and for some reason I couldn't find it in the documentation.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  If this is a self-answered question, you should write the question and answer separately ("Q & A style").

Comment: Thanks for that. Noted.

Answer (score 1):

So the answer was quite simple. I don't know how to do it within the autocomplete_light class itself but this is a completely suitable solution:

```
zip = autocomplete_light.ChoiceField('ZipAutocomplete',label='')
```